# Does the anti derivative of $\int \frac{1}{ax+b} dx$ have multiple answers?

Tags: integration, solution-verification

$$∫ \dfrac{1}{ax+b} dx = \dfrac{1}{a}\log_{e}{|ax+b|} + c$$

but if you factor out $1/a$ from the integral first then the anti derivative becomes

$$\cfrac{1}{a}\log_{e}\left|x+\dfrac{b}{a}\right| + c$$

which is correct? If both why?

Comment: $ c$ is not the same.

Comment: The constant of integration would be different for each expression, and that makes the expressions the same. You can verify this yourself by graphing both expressions (without $c$) and observing that they are identical apart from the fact one is shifted upwards

Comment: $\log(ax+b)=\log a+\log(x+(b/a))$.

Comment: The title is not good. You can't take derivatives or antiderivatives of curves.

Comment: Any antiderivative problem has multiple answers.  Take any answer and add any constant, get another answer.  Your two answers are an example of this.

Comment: Any thoughts on these comments, CZ?